# Broken Nav Links?

Tags: html, hyperlink, nav

For some reason, my code on [this website-in-process](http://kadehall.com/preview/awards/faq/) isn't letting me click on the links in my nav bar. The Home, FAQ, and About links should all be live, but nothing's happening. This is the case on all three of the pages I currently have coded and up for preview.
(If you look in the code, the Contact link is listed, but it doesn't link to anything; that's temporary, and on purpose for now.)

The problem comes when you try and click on those links. Nothing happens, and a new page is not opened. However, if you right-click them, and select "Open Link in New Tab," they work just fine. I can't figure out what's broken, and it feels like it should be an easy fix.

Any suggestions?

--EDIT--

Nav Code in Question:

```
<nav id="fixedbar">
    <div class="nav-content">
        <ul class="navmain navfixed">
            <a href="http://www.kadehall.com/preview/awards/"><li class="navspot">home</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="navspot">store</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="navspot">gallery</li></a>
            <a href="http://www.kadehall.com/preview/awards/faq/"><li class="navspot stay" id="end-leftnav">FAQ</li></a>
            <li><a href="#top"><img src="parts/header/column-circle.png" id="columncircle"/></a></li>
            <a href="http://www.kadehall.com/preview/awards/about/"><li class="navspot" id="start-rightnav">about</li></a>
            <a href="http://www.kadehall.com/preview/awards/contact/"><li class="navspot">contact</li></a>
            <!-- start social -->
            <li class="navsoc">
                <a href="#"><img src="parts/social/facebook.png" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="parts/social/etsy.png" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="parts/social/pinterest.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- There is also an alternate nav for when the page is not scrolling,
     but the only difference is the use of id="fixedbar" -->
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of JavaScript.

See the html source code of your FAQ page at line `269` :

```
$('#navigation a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

The [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) function cancel the default event when you click on the link.

Comment: I thought you was talking about the JavaScript code. Ok the HTML is not W3C correct, but this will never block a link to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your **a** tags inside the **li**, this is your current code

[image]

when it should be :

```
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` tag can only have an `<li>` as it's child. Since your `<a>` is outside your `<li>` so the `<a>` tag is pushed out of the `<ul>`.

Insert those `<a>` tags inside your `<li>`'s

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrectly structured.

```
<ul class="navmain">
  <a href="/awards">
    <li class="navspot">home</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Should be

```
<ul class="navmain">
  <li class="navspot">
    <a href="/awards">home</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You cannot nest anything than a `li` element inside `ul` or `ol` lists.